# Can't deploy universal app to phone with Windows 10 Mobile Tech Preview

Tags: deployment, win-universal-app, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I have a developer unlocked **Lumia 635** just yesterday updated to [Windows 10 Mobile Technical Preview](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/preview-download-phone) (OS version: **10.0.12562.84**).

After creating "Blank App (Windows Universal)" targeting **Windows Phone 10** in Visual Studio 2015 RC and tried to deploy it to the device (and have changed configuration to ARM for that exactly purpose) I've got this error:

> Error : DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: A Prerequisite for an install could not be satisfied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073CFD)

<strike>After quick look at the app "references" it is turns out there are some of them specific to *Application Insights* (and few others) with disregard to the fact that I've specifically **unchecked** the *Application Insights* integration on project creation dialog before (surprise!). So I've removed them all leaving only the following (seems like unremovable):</strike>

1. Analyzes
2. .NET for Windows Store apps
3. Windows Universal

But this didn't help, unfortunately - still can't deploy this "default" app to the phone.

Though, deployment of my current working universal app that target **Windows Phone 8.1**, to this phone was just flawless.

<strike>Working OS is *Windows 8.1 Pro*, if that matter.</strike>

**Update**

Strike-through text above is not important anymore, see accepted answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm on the .NET/UWP team. The official answer from Microsoft is here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn706236.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Let me write out the steps from that link above. These steps apply today (May 20th 2015, using VS2015 RC that was released at BUILD.) Deploying to mobile was not possible prior to May14, when the correct build of Win10 Mobile came out.

**Your machine should be running Windows 10, build 10074 or higher, from here: [https://insider.windows.com/](https://insider.windows.com/__)**

- I installed it "clean" on my SurfacePro1. To do this, first download the ISO of Windows10 from http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/preview-download, and then use "Rufus" http://rufus.akeo.ie/ to create an installable USB image from the ISO. Within Rufus, for my SurfacePro1, I had to choose "FAT32" and "GPT for UEFI". I don't know what you need on other machines.

**Install VS2015 RC from here: [https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-downloads-vs.aspx](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-downloads-vs.aspx__)**

- During installation, you get to choose which components to install. You should choose "Windows 10 tools and emulators". Installation takes from one to several hours.
- It will install Windows 10 SDK version 10069.
- There are some glitches with the installer. If you go back to AddRemovePrograms and modify which components of VS2015 RC are installed, then it ends up installing more than it really should.
- When VS runs for the first time, it asks if you want to sign in. I always used to click "no" and it'd then ask me more configuration questions. But if I answer "yes" and I sign in, then it bypasses all those configuration questions, and ends up being quicker. Lesson learned: I now always sign in.

**You can run Win10 apps upon emulators. The emulators came with the Win10 SDK, and so are running version 10069 of the Win10.Mobile operating system.**

**You can run Win10 apps on your local machine. To do this you local machine must be Win10.Desktop version 10074 or higher and must be unlocked.**

- Instructions for unlocking are at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn706236.aspx. Here's a "TL;DR" version:
- Run gpedit.msc > Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > App Package Deployment. Then right-click to enable two things,
- "Allow all trusted apps to install"
- "Allow development of Windows Store apps"

**You can run Win10 apps on your phone. To do this your phone must be Win10.Mobile version 10080 or higher (which came out on May 14th). Your phone must be unlocked.**

- Instructions for unlocking are at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn706236.aspx. Here's a "TL;DR" version:
- Plug your phone in by USB. Run "Windows Phone Developer Registration" tool from your desktop.

The key fact about Win10 is that you can write software against one particular SDK (e.g. the 10069 SDK that came out at //BUILD), and still run it on a more recent version of Win10 (e.g. 10074 that's current for Win10.Desktop program, or 10080 that's current for Win10.Mobile insider program).

In the .appxmanifest file, MinVersion="10.0.10069.0" says that your app will refuse to deploy to any machine which is running a lower version of Win10.

In the .appxmanifest file, MaxVersionTested="10.0.10074.0" says that if your app is deployed to a machine which is running a higher version of Win10, then it might have to do "quirking".

Both of these things are controlled by the Project>Properties dialog, and are actually stored in the .csproj/.vbproj.

The answers by @user4855870, @Rexobias and @Sevenate were hacks. They were sticking in an artificially low version for MinVersion to work around the fact they hadn't yet updated their devices. That's a fair approach (and I did it while I was waiting for Win10.Mobile 10080 build to be released). But now that it has been released, there's no need for these hacks, and you should just update your device.

Comment: The final release of the Windows 10 SDK now precludes deploying to any phones running Windows 10, whether or not they've been developer unlocked.

Any word on when deploying to phones running the Insider Preview will be allowed?

Comment: @LucianWischik This is not works for me. Both my win10 pc and win10 phone is in developer mode, my phone is connected over usb, but at deploy I always got this message: **DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: Element not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070490) SolutionName** I was running a genuine Win10 what was upgraded to be an Insider Preview

Answer (score 2):

I found that:
Solution Explorer -> Right click on project -> properties -> debug -> on start options -> target device: choose device and save.

Deploy again!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great!  This is the only thing that helped me :)!

Answer (score 1):

In Package.appxmanifest try changing the TargetDeviceFamily to the following:

```
<TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.1.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.1.0" />
```

Comment: That resulted in an error: "Unable to activate Windows Store app ' _app id_ '. The activateion request failed with error 'The subsystem needed to support the image type is not present'." Please note that test app was created from default project template for Windows Universal "Blank App" (for Windows 10) without any modifications after creation.

Comment: This isn't needed. A better approach is to upgrade your device to a build more recent than the 10069 SDK that you're using. Also, putting that value of "MaxVersionTested" may result in weird quirking behavior from the OS.

Answer (score 1):

I just faced the same problem described by @Sevenate.

Following the response of @user4855870 I'm finally able to deploy my blank Universal App to my Lumia 520 running W10 TP.

1) On the phone, go to Settings, System, About, More Info and write down the OS version (in my case it is 10.0.12534.59);

2) On Visual Studio, open Package.appxmanifest and in the same line mentioned by @user4855870 on the "MinVersion" write "10.0.1.0" and on the "MaxVersionTested" write the OS version you got from your phone.

```
<TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.1.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.12534.59" />
```

My blank Universal App works on computer and phone as it should ;)

Comment: I've tried this way as well, but still getting another error ([screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/VLL7ifc.png))

Comment: That's wrong. The MaxVersionTested is using a completely different number-sequence from the Settings>System>About>MoreInfo OS version. The MaxVersionTested should be 10069 (the version of the SDK you installed). It would be meaningful to put 10074 (the current version of Win10.Desktop as of May 20th). It would be meaningful to put 10080 (the current version of Win10.Phone as of May 20th).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've managed to finally deploy this sample app to the Windows Phone 10.

### Short answer

In your project's **Package.appxmanifest** change the `MinVersion` from "10.0.10069.0" to "**1.0.22816.1**" (unexpected, hah?) like this:

```
<Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal"
                        MinVersion="1.0.22816.1"
                        MaxVersionTested="10.0.10069.0" />
</Dependencies>
```

### Longer answer

After you'll build the project just created from new "Windows 10 Universal Blank App" template in VS2015 RC the original **Package.appxmanifest** available from solution explorer in Visual Studio will copied to `YourBlankWin10PhoneProject\bin\x86\Debug\Core\AppxManifest.xml` (notice the **Core** subfolder in the path) and *updated* with new dependency - **.NET Core Runtime** package:

```
<Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal"
                        MinVersion="10.0.10069.0"
                        MaxVersionTested="10.0.10069.0" />
    <PackageDependency Name="Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.0"
                       MinVersion="1.0.22816.1"
                       Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation,
                       L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US" />
</Dependencies>
```

(Don't confuse with *another* copy of the original *unmodified* version of the manifest at `YourBlankWin10PhoneProject\bin\x86\Debug\AppxManifest.xml`)

As you could see `MinVersion` for both dependencies is different and the application's one is **greater** then the Core Runtime component's. Now if you update `MinVersion` in the original **Package.appxmanifest** from the solution explorer to match the `MinVersion` of the `Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.0` package, i.e. to **1.0.22816.1**, next time you'll build the project the *Core* copy of the manifest will be updated accordingly:

```
<Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal"
                        MinVersion="1.0.22816.1"
                        MaxVersionTested="10.0.10069.0" />
    <PackageDependency Name="Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.0"
                       MinVersion="1.0.22816.1"
                       Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation,
                       L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US" />
</Dependencies>
```

Now application should be deployed to the phone without problem.

PS. Found the hint to solve this in [Deep Dive into XAML and .NET Universal Windows App Development](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/2-790) video, fast forward to **0:19:50**.

Comment: These are incorrect version numbers that you're getting from wrong places. The "PackageDependency" version number 1.0.22816 refers to the build number of VS (where the Microsoft.Net.CoreRuntime package is built). The "TargetDeviceFamily" version number "10.0.10069.0" refers to the version of the OS. Your answer only accidentally works because "1.0.22816.1" is lower than "10.0.10051" (or whatever is the OS version of the device you're deploying to).

Comment: @LucianWischik, back then I've tried different lower version numbers, but for some reason only I've mentioned worked for me. Anyway, now it is not relevant anymore, thanks for update!

Answer (score -1):

Deploying a Windows 10 app to phones is not currently supported*. The functionality is expected in a future update (to either Windows 10's phone version, the developer tools, or both).

For now you can use the emulators to test apps on the phone form factors.

edit: here's the official word from Microsoft:
[MS Developer Tools Blog link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2015/03/23/visual-studio-tools-for-windows-10-technical-preview.aspx)

*it looks like some are able to hack it to work

Comment: I wonder why Microsoft have not included this functionality when such a simple hack seems to work.

Comment: I guess this is more like "not yet implemented" rather then "as designed". Pretty sure with next major update (or at least in RTM) this version misconfiguration will be fixed.

Comment: As of May 18th, it is supported. That's when the Phone Insiders build 10080 came out. It has a higher version than the 10069 SDK that came in VS2015 RC at Build.